# How to change button to disabled once it is clicked in Vue JS app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wanted to know how do I change a button to disabled once it is clicked, but the data comes from an rest api, so I want to the button disabled only on that list item and not all buttons. I can't see where to do this in VueJS.

My component code is:

```
<template>
  <div class="container search">
    <List :List="List"/>
    <!-- <div class='div' v-bind:class="[isActive ? 'red' : 'blue']" @click="toggleClass()"></div> -->

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">{{title}}</h1>
      <p class="lead">{{intro}}</p>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <p v-if="validated" :class="errorTextClass">Enter a valid search term</p>

      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3"
        v-on:click="refreshPage"
        v-if="result.length > 1"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon icon="redo"/> Start again
      </button>
      <input
        class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="Search"
        v-model="search"
        required
        autocomplete="off"
        id="search"
      >

      <div v-for="(result, index) in result" :key="index">
        <div class="media mb-4">
          <img
            :src="resizeArtworkUrl(result)"
            alt="Album Cover"
            class="album-cover align-self-start mr-3"
          >
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="mt-0">
              <!-- <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
                v-on:click="addItem(result)"
              >
                <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
              </button>-->

              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
                v-on:click="addItem(result)"
                >
                <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
              </button>
              <b>{{result.collectionName}}</b>
            </h4>
            <h6 class="mt-0">{{result.artistName}}</h6>
            <p class="mt-0">{{result.primaryGenreName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div :class="loadingClass" v-if="loading"></div>

      <button
        class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block mb-3"
        type="submit"
        v-on:click="getData"
        v-if="result.length < 1"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon icon="search"/> Search
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import List from "../components/myList.vue";

export default {
  name: "Hero",
  components: {
    List
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      title: "Simple Search",
      isActive: true,
      intro: "This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style.",
      subintro:
        "It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out.",
      result: [],
      errors: [],
      List: [],
      search: "",
      loading: "",
      message: false,
      isValidationAllowed: false,
      loadingClass: "loading",
      errorTextClass: "error-text"
    };
  },

  watch: {
    search: function(val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.result = [];
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    validated() {
      return this.isValidationAllowed && !this.search;
    },
    isDisabled: function() {
        return !this.terms;
      }
  },

  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      this.isValidationAllowed = true;
      this.loading = true;
      fetch(`https://restit.api.com`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.result = data.results;
          this.loading = false;
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
          console.log(data);
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
        });
    },

    toggleClass: function() {
      // Check value
      if (this.isActive) {
        this.isActive = false;
      } else {
        this.isActive = true;
      }
    },

    refreshPage: function() {
      this.search = "";
    },
    addItem: function(result) {
      this.List.push(result);
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(result);
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
    },

    resizeArtworkUrl(result) {
      return result.artworkUrl100.replace("100x100", "160x160");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.loading {
  background-image: url("../assets/Rolling-1s-42px.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.error-text {
  color: red;
}

.media {
  text-align: left;
}

.album-cover {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

It is the `addItem button` which code is:

```
<button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
   v-on:click="addItem(result)"
   >
   <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
</button>
```

**List component**

```
<template>
  <div class="mb-5 container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 btn-block">
      My List
      <span class="badge badge-light">{{List.length}}</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="list-group" v-for="(result, index) in List" :key="index">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <b>{{result.collectionName}}</b>
        <h6 class="mt-0">{{result.artistName}}</h6>
        <p class="mt-0">{{result.primaryGenreName}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
</ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
      'List',
  ],

};
</script>
```

So the idea is users can add an item to a list component but obviously they can't keep adding that item, so that is why I need to disable the button after clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
<button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
   v-on:click="addItem(result)"
   :disabled="result.disableButton">
   <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
</button>
```

And in your method:

```
addItem: function(result) {
      result.disableButton = true; // Or result['disableButton'] = true;
      this.List.push(result);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks that nearly works, but that disables the button on all the other list items from the rest api, I need to just target the one I am clicking.

Comment: Ok. Can u save one more field to your result? And instead of asking for `disableButton` variable you can ask something like `result.buttonDisabled`

Comment: I just updated the code above with the list component too that when you click the add button the item goes into the list (List component)

Comment: Did you try `@click.once`?

Comment: No but doing `@click.once` will not trigger the `addItem` event handler